# Not able to see "DocuSign Status" lightning component in Lightning App Builder post upgrade to latest version on DocuSign?

Tags: appexchange, docusign

We are preparing for lightning migration of our org and as part of the preparation, we are also evaluating the DocuSign application that we use. We found that the latest version of DocuSign is lightning ready, so I upgraded it on one of the POC Sandbox to explore more on how to configure and use it by following the DocuSign for Salesforce Lightning Experience guide. The guide talks about two components that we can use in lightning experience i.e. "DocuSign Status" and "Send with DocuSign" but somehow I am not able to see the "DocuSign Status" lightning component in the lightning app builder or in the sandbox or in installed package component.

The "Send with DocuSign" lightning component was available and I used it just fine. I tried re-upgrading the DocuSign application again but still not able to see the "DocuSign Status" lightning component in the Lightning app builder to play around it.

Did anyone face similar issues? If yes, please let me know how to fix this?

Thank You,
Nilesh Dethe

Comment: Have you checked with Docusign support?

Comment: Hi David, The first step I took was a raised case with DocuSign Support. Then they asked me to contact their Sales team for further assistance, So I emailed their Sales team but I didn't get any response so I again contacted DocuSign Support and surprisingly they asked me to post it here in StackExchange. If I don't get any help here I will probably tweet it to DocuSign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research and continuous follow up with the DocuSign Support and Sales Team, I finally found the answer to my above questions in the DocuSign Community Forum.

The Solution is - The DocuSign Status Lightning Component is a separate installation and not part of the DocuSign AppExchange manage package offering.

You'll have to search the Lightning Component store for DocuSign Status and install it.

Reference: https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00085996

If anyone has further questions, please post it here

Thank you,

Nilesh Dethe